# Is there any pyspark method to read multiple file with different header

Tags: pyspark

I have to migrate multiple files(around 2000) in same folder in azure blob storage. I want to read each file with header(as header is different for every file).
And write it into destination folder.

Is there anyway I can do it parallel via pyspark?

I am using below code, but it is only picking header from first file, which is producing wrong output.

```
Df.read.option(“header”, “true”).parquet(directory/*.parquet)

Df.write.option(“header”,”true”).csv(directory)
```

Please help me if you know how can I read all the files with source headers of their own.

Thanks!

Comment: This could be useful : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55677498/spark-load-multiple-files-analyze-individually-merge-results-and-save

Comment: I believe it can be done **programmatically**, but not **parallelly**